# Intermittent ethernet configuration problem based on presence/absence of 4th SSD

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, ethernet

Ubuntu Server 22.04.3

My computer has 4 SSDs. With all SSDs in place, the computer boots and picks up an IP from the router. When I shutdown, then remove the fourth SSD, then boot up, the computer boots and fails to pick up an IP from the router. If I re-insert the fourth SSD then boot up, the computer picks up an IP from the router. I have gone through this process (of removing and re-inserting and rebooting) any number of times for the same results.

I have recently purchased the computer with no OS. I've installed Ubuntu server 22.04.3. During OS installation, I configured software RAID-1 on the first two SSDs, and all four SSDs were marked as bootable and created with the same partitions, with the intention of adding (after the OS installation was completed) the third and fourth SSDs as hot spares for the RAID device.

The error I'm describing occurs both before and after the raid device completes its initial synchronization, and occurs before I add SSD-3 and SSD-4 to the raid device as hot spares.

Below are some screenshots related to what I've described above. Does anyone have any suggestion/s as to how I can address this? Or what may be causing this issue?

[Here's what the screen looks like when I boot and logon with all four SSDs in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Yhjv.jpg)

[Here's what the screen looks like when I boot and logon with only three SSDs in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb2lx.jpg)

In relation to the screenshot above, when I originally came across this issue, I actually started with just two SSDs in place (and configured for RAID-1). Everything worked well with the two SSDs in place. When I removed an SSD (to test the RAID), then booted and logged in, the problem was different. Unlike the screenshot above, the network adapter was not listed at all; then, after I replaced the SSD and rebooted, all would be fine (and the network adapter would properly appear in the output).

[Here's a photo of the motherboard box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TVjf.jpg)

Here's some things I see after installation (with all four SSDs in place),

[lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZQsG.png)

[ls -la /dev/disk/by-partuuid/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ltF.png)

[efibootmgr -v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRE6v.png)

[uname -r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnXMh.png)

[sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpwzB.png)